# Trying to get product(s) that have been ordered the least amount of times

Tags: sql, mariadb, left-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I want to find out the products that have been ordered the least amount of times without using order by desc or top 1 etc. My query seems to get the min calculation right but the productID and name don't match

```
SELECT T.ProductID, ProductName, MIN(Total_Quantity)
FROM (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) as Total_Quantity
      FROM orderdetails
      GROUP BY orderdetails.ProductID) as T
      JOIN products p on T.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

my code is pasted above and this is the output:

[Total Minimum Qty Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn4V6.png)

Here is the sum of quantity per product ordered

[Total Qty per product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIXgX.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out the products that have been ordered the least amount of times

This sounds like `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.productid, p.productname, sum(od.total_quantity) as total_quantity
from products p
left join orderdetails od on od.productid = p.productid
group by p.productid
having sum(od.total_quantity) > 3
```